# in bash, why is a variable visible in the shell, but not in a shell script

Tags: bash

When I run the 'set' command in a bash shell, I see a variable has a value. However, when I run the 'set' command in a bash script, the variable does not exist. Why? How might I make this happen?

```
AxOS(7iq1) root:/mnt/ax/scratch/roshi# set
--snip--
SERIAL_NUMBER=7iq1
--snip--
AxOS(7iq1) root:/mnt/ax/scratch/roshi#
```

My shell script tmp.sh contains

```
#!/bin/bash
svcid=`set | grep ^SERIAL_NUMBER | awk '{ split($1,a,"=");print a[2] }'`
echo ${svcid}
```

If I execute the script as follows, I get no output

```
AxOS(7iq1) root:/mnt/ax/scratch/roshi# ./tmp.sh

AxOS(7iq1) root:/mnt/ax/scratch/roshi#
```

If I execute the script as (first suggested by Doon)

```
AxOS(7iq1) root:/mnt/ax/scratch/roshi# . ./tmp.sh
7iq1
AxOS(7iq1) root:/mnt/ax/scratch/roshi#
```

Comment: Please post a (small) example

Comment: normally when you run a script it runs in a subshell. so once it exits all changes are lost.  To run it in the current shell run it like `. script.sh`  and it will run in the current shell. does that fix the issue?  else as @Useless said, example please

Comment: @Doon: That fixed it. But I'm confused as to why. I thought the . was a synonym for source the given file. I guess that makes sense. Source the current file which begins with #!/bin/bash so it runs the script. Does that make sense?

Comment: it does source it. the dot or source operator executes the script in the current shell context.  Normally when you use it execute a script it is to pull in config, but it still executes it.

Comment: That must be the most convoluted way to say `svcid=$SERIAL_NUMBER` that I have ever seen.

Answer (score 3):

Some (but not necessarily all) shell variables are marked for export to the environment. Only these variables are visible in a child process (such as a shell script). For example:

```
$ x=3         # shell variable
$ export y=5  # shell variable exported to the environment
$ cat example.sh
echo "value of x: $x"
echo "value of y: $y"
$ bash example.sh
example of x:
example of y: 5
```

Comment: My problem has been solved, so thanks for the response anyways.

I did however try what you suggest and the only part that did not appear to work for me was 

bash example.sh

I could be wrong, but doing it this way, causes example.sh to be run in a new shell, which brings up the original problem. I need something in the existing shell to be available in the subordinate shell script, and the only way to do that is to either pass it in as proposed by hd1 below, or source it as suggested by Doon.

Answer (score 0):

It's because the shell script runs in a separate process with a separate environment from the caller. You want to use the `env VAR=[value] [script-command]` to solve this problem. You asked for an example, here you go:

```
% bash # I use zsh and this is a paste from the terminal
$ echo "echo $VAR" > /tmp/echo.sh
$ sh /tmp/echo.sh

$ env VAR='hello' sh /tmp/echo.sh
hello
$
```